# strcats func crashing application

Tags: c++

I trying strcat_s function and crashing application. How to work this code?

```
char *test = "hello ";
strcat_s(test, strlen(test), "guys");
// like output "hello guys" but application crashing...
```

Comment: I don't work with additional libs.

Comment: @EminFurkanTürkmen: `std::string` is not an "additional" library. It is a part of C++. Unless you're on an embedded platform without the C++ library facilities, your code would not pass code review on my team.

Comment: Have a look at this question on how to use c code in c++

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448014/how-to-use-c-code-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Since you're writing C++, you should be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), not `char*`.

```
std::string test = "hello ";
test += "guys;
```

And if you need to pass that string to existing C++ code as a pointer, use the [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method:

```
extern void foo(const char*);
foo(test.c_str());
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to modify a string literal. That is not allowed.

Your compiler should at least be warning you about that `char* test`, which should be `const char* test` to enforce immutability. In fact, since C++11, your code won't even compile!

Answer (score 3):

In C++03

```
char *test = "hello ";
```

Is a deprecated conversion of a `const char[N]` to a `char*`.  Trying to modify it with `strcat` is undefined behavior.

In C++11 and above You have ill formed code.

```
char *test = "hello ";
```

Is not legal C++.  The type of `"hello "` is a `const char[N]`.  That means when you call `strcat` you try to modify a constant string.  If you turn up your warning level to compiler should tell you this.

You really should be using `std::string` and then you could have

```
std::string test = "hello ";
test += "guys;
```

And it will work just fine.

Comment: Technically, in C++03 (which the OP must be using), this is a deprecated conversion followed (later) by an undefined mutation. Since C++11 the initialisation is ill-formed though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Should I add that?  I just figured since it was tagged C++ I should answer using the current standard.

Comment: Yes, I think so - it's clear the OP is not using C++11 so to say the code is ill-formed is misleading at best :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you think about this revision?

Answer (score 2):

The pointer *test* points to read-only memory. Modifing the read-only memory causes app crash.

This will work:

```
char test[128];
strcpy(test, "hello ");
strcat_s(test, strlen(test), "guys");
```

Comment: You don't need the strcpy() - `char test[128] = "hello";` does the job.