# Creating CUDA C library using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, cuda

I've the following code structure for my library

```
|-build
|-example
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |-main_VecAdd.cu
|-include
    |-VonNeumann
        |-utils.h
        |-VecAdd.h
    |-CMakeLists.txt
|-src
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    |-utils.c
    |-VecAdd.c
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

`CMakeLists.txt` for folders `example`, `include`, `src` and `main_folder` are as follows (in order respectively):

```
project(VonNeumann LANGUAGES CUDA C)

add_executable(main_VecAdd main_VecAdd.cu)

set_target_properties(VonNeumann PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

target_link_libraries(main_VecAdd 
    PRIVATE
    VonNeumann)
```

```
project(VonNeumann LANGUAGES CUDA C)
```

```
project(VonNeumann LANGUAGES CUDA C)

add_library(VonNeumann utils.c VecAdd.c)

target_include_directories(VonNeumann
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
project(VonNeumann LANGUAGES CUDA C)

# Adding subdirectories
add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)

# Giving an option to include code in examples or not
option(BUILD_EXAMPLES "Whether or not to build examples" ON)
if (BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    message(STATUS "Building examples...")
    add_subdirectory(example)
endif()
```

When I run `cmake ..` from build directory, everything works well however I get the following error when I run `make` command:

```
[ 16%] Linking C static library libVonNeumann.a
[ 50%] Built target VonNeumann
[ 66%] Linking CUDA device code CMakeFiles/main_VecAdd.dir/cmake_device_link.o
[ 83%] Linking CUDA executable main_VecAdd
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main_VecAdd.dir/main_VecAdd.cu.o: in function `main':
tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `RandVecFP32(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `RandVecFP32(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `ZeroVecFP32(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `PrintVec(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `PrintVec(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x166): undefined reference to `PrintVec(float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `VecAddFP32(float*, float*, float*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: tmpxft_000058c9_00000000-6_main_VecAdd.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `PrintVec(float*, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [example/CMakeFiles/main_VecAdd.dir/build.make:105: example/main_VecAdd] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:163: example/CMakeFiles/main_VecAdd.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I know that the error is because of failed linking but I can't figure out how to resolve this.

P.S. I've tested this same code without CUDA part and it works just fine.

Comment: This is a C versus C++ linkage issue. CUDA uses C++ linkage

Comment: So the only option is to switch to C++ completely?

Comment: No, but then you would need to modify the CUDA code to export the symbols you need to call from your C code with C linkage

Comment: As I'm just starting out, I think it's easier to switch my code to C++. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @talonmies suggests, the problem is likely you trying to use functions implemented in your `.cu` file, in your `.c` file: CUDA  uses "C++ linkage", that the function symbols appear in a certain way in the compiled object file, which differs from how function symbols appear when compiled using C.

To allow your C code to be used by C++ code, you must adapt the declarations to be read differently in C++ (or CUDA), in `utils.h` and `VecAdd.h` like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void PrintVec(float*, int);
// ... or whatever you're defining

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

See also:

- https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp
- [How to use C code in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448014/how-to-use-c-code-in-c)

---

By the way - you're using too many `CMakeLists.txt` files. You don't need one of these for every folder. In fact, for a project as small as yours, a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` and perhaps another one for the examples would have sufficed. Subdirectory-specific `CMakeLists.txt` files are appropriate where the contents of the subdirectory is worked on relatively independently, and the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` does not need to be aware of the dependencies and other configuration work towards producing the targets that *do* get used outside.